# Definitive guide for styling react-tooltip components?

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion, react-tooltip

I am using react-tooltip, react-emotion.

I cannot figure out how to style the span in order to override default styles.

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import styled from 'react-emotion';

const myTooltip = (Wrapper, toolTip) => {
  class TooltipWrap extends PureComponent {
    render() {
      return (
        <span
          data-tip={toolTip}
          data-delay-show="250"
          data-place="bottom"
          className={TooltipStyle}
        >
          <Wrapper
            {...this.props}
          />
        </span>
      );
    }
  }

  return TooltipWrap;
};

export default withToolTip;

const TooltipStyle = styled.span ({
  color: 'red !important';
  fontSize: '48px !important';
})
```

Anyone have any tips or a specific definitive guide on how to style this span so I can override the defaults in react-tooltip?

The documentation is pretty spotty, and there's literally no examples anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue but was able to override the default styles using `styled` components and passing it the ReactTooltip component

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import styled from 'react-emotion';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';

const myTooltip = (Wrapper, toolTip) => {
  class TooltipWrap extends PureComponent {
    render() {
      return (
        <span
          data-tip={toolTip}
          data-delay-show="250"
          data-place="bottom"
        >
          // Replace ReactTooltip component with styled one
          <ReactTooltipStyled type="dark" />
          <Wrapper
            {...this.props}
          />
        </span>
      );
    }
  }

  return TooltipWrap;
};

export default withToolTip;

export const ReactTooltipStyled = styled(ReactTooltip)`
  &.place-bottom {
    color: red;
    font-size: 48px;
  }
`;
```

Using this method all you would need to do is import the newly styled component into your React file and replace the original `ReactTooltip` with the `ReactTooltipStyled` component.